# Plotly Sunburst Chart not rendering after changing the underlying dataset in the Plotly Example

Tags: python, plotly, sunburst-diagram

> https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/
> Sunburst chart with a continuous colorscale

I have been working through the Sunburst Chart examples on the above Plotly website. I changed the example to use a different dataset but I'm having trouble getting the altered example code to render in the browser. I have written to Excel the hierarchical dataframes produced by the example and by my altered script.

I'm running the script using Visual Studio Code on Windows 10.

Using Python 3.9.6 venv: Anaconda
Plotly: 5.3.1
Plotly-Express: 0.4.1
Pandas: 1.3.2

Any thoughts on what I missed that would be causing the Sunburst Chart to not render properly in either Microsoft Edge or Google Chrome?

> **Altered Example Code**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

raw = pd.DataFrame(px.data.tips())

df = raw[["sex", "time", "day", "total_bill", "tip"]].sort_values(["sex", "time", "day"])

df.insert(0, "Unnamed: 0", range(0, 0 + len(df)))

df.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)

print(df.head())

levels = ['day', 'time', 'sex'] # levels used for the hierarchical chart
color_columns = ['tip', 'total_bill']
value_column = 'total_bill'

def build_hierarchical_dataframe(df, levels, value_column, color_columns=None):
    """
    Build a hierarchy of levels for Sunburst or Treemap charts.

    Levels are given starting from the bottom to the top of the hierarchy,
    ie the last level corresponds to the root.
    """
    df_all_trees = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'parent', 'value', 'color'])
    for i, level in enumerate(levels):
        df_tree = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'parent', 'value', 'color'])
        dfg = df.groupby(levels[i:]).sum()
        dfg = dfg.reset_index()
        df_tree['id'] = dfg[level].copy()
        if i < len(levels) - 1:
            df_tree['parent'] = dfg[levels[i+1]].copy()
        else:
            df_tree['parent'] = 'total'
        df_tree['value'] = dfg[value_column]
        df_tree['color'] = dfg[color_columns[0]] / dfg[color_columns[1]]
        df_all_trees = df_all_trees.append(df_tree, ignore_index=True)
    total = pd.Series(dict(id='total', parent='',
                              value=df[value_column].sum(),
                              color=df[color_columns[0]].sum() / df[color_columns[1]].sum()))
    df_all_trees = df_all_trees.append(total, ignore_index=True)
    return df_all_trees

df_all_trees = build_hierarchical_dataframe(df, levels, value_column, color_columns)

average_score = df['tip'].sum() / df['total_bill'].sum()

fig = make_subplots(1, 2, specs=[[{"type": "domain"}, {"type": "domain"}]],)

fig.add_trace(go.Sunburst(
    labels=df_all_trees['id'],
    parents=df_all_trees['parent'],
    values=df_all_trees['value'],
    branchvalues='total',
    marker=dict(
        colors=df_all_trees['color'],
        colorscale='RdBu',
        cmid=average_score),
    hovertemplate='<b>%{label} </b> <br> Sales: %{value}<br> Success rate: %{color:.2f}',
    name=''
    ), 1, 1)

fig.add_trace(go.Sunburst(
    labels=df_all_trees['id'],
    parents=df_all_trees['parent'],
    values=df_all_trees['value'],
    branchvalues='total',
    marker=dict(
        colors=df_all_trees['color'],
        colorscale='RdBu',
        cmid=average_score),
    hovertemplate='<b>%{label} </b> <br> Sales: %{value}<br> Success rate: %{color:.2f}',
    maxdepth=2
    ), 1, 2)

fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=10, b=10, r=10, l=10))
fig.show()
```

> **Original Code From Example**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/sales_success.csv')
print(df.head())

levels = ['salesperson', 'county', 'region'] # levels used for the hierarchical chart
color_columns = ['sales', 'calls']
value_column = 'calls'

def build_hierarchical_dataframe(df, levels, value_column, color_columns=None):
    """
    Build a hierarchy of levels for Sunburst or Treemap charts.

    Levels are given starting from the bottom to the top of the hierarchy,
    ie the last level corresponds to the root.
    """
    df_all_trees = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'parent', 'value', 'color'])
    for i, level in enumerate(levels):
        df_tree = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'parent', 'value', 'color'])
        dfg = df.groupby(levels[i:]).sum()
        dfg = dfg.reset_index()
        df_tree['id'] = dfg[level].copy()
        if i < len(levels) - 1:
            df_tree['parent'] = dfg[levels[i+1]].copy()
        else:
            df_tree['parent'] = 'total'
        df_tree['value'] = dfg[value_column]
        df_tree['color'] = dfg[color_columns[0]] / dfg[color_columns[1]]
        df_all_trees = df_all_trees.append(df_tree, ignore_index=True)
    total = pd.Series(dict(id='total', parent='',
                              value=df[value_column].sum(),
                              color=df[color_columns[0]].sum() / df[color_columns[1]].sum()))
    df_all_trees = df_all_trees.append(total, ignore_index=True)
    return df_all_trees


df_all_trees = build_hierarchical_dataframe(df, levels, value_column, color_columns)
average_score = df['sales'].sum() / df['calls'].sum()

fig = make_subplots(1, 2, specs=[[{"type": "domain"}, {"type": "domain"}]],)

display(df_all_trees)

fig.add_trace(go.Sunburst(
    labels=df_all_trees['id'],
    parents=df_all_trees['parent'],
    values=df_all_trees['value'],
    branchvalues='total',
    marker=dict(
        colors=df_all_trees['color'],
        colorscale='RdBu',
        cmid=average_score),
    hovertemplate='<b>%{label} </b> <br> Sales: %{value}<br> Success rate: %{color:.2f}',
    name=''
    ), 1, 1)

fig.add_trace(go.Sunburst(
    labels=df_all_trees['id'],
    parents=df_all_trees['parent'],
    values=df_all_trees['value'],
    branchvalues='total',
    marker=dict(
        colors=df_all_trees['color'],
        colorscale='RdBu',
        cmid=average_score),
    hovertemplate='<b>%{label} </b> <br> Sales: %{value}<br> Success rate: %{color:.2f}',
    maxdepth=2
    ), 1, 2)

#fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=10, b=10, r=10, l=10))
fig.show()
```

> **Example output form df_all_trees used as input rendering the figure**

|  | id | parent | value | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Fri | Dinner | 71.55 | 0.196366 |
| 2 | Fri | Lunch | 55.76 | 0.196915 |
| 3 | Fri | Lunch | 34.16 | 0.166862 |
| 4 | Sat | Dinner | 551.05 | 0.142365 |
| 5 | Sat | Dinner | 1227.35 | 0.148246 |
| 6 | Sun | Dinner | 357.7 | 0.169444 |
| 7 | Sun | Dinner | 1269.46 | 0.147133 |
| 8 | Thur | Dinner | 18.78 | 0.159744 |
| 10 | Thur | Lunch | 561.44 | 0.159251 |
| 11 | Dinner | Female | 999.08 | 0.156254 |
| 12 | Dinner | Male | 2661.22 | 0.146534 |
| 13 | Lunch | Female | 571.87 | 0.158078 |
| 14 | Lunch | Male | 595.6 | 0.159688 |
| 15 | Female | total | 1570.95 | 0.156918 |
| 16 | Male | total | 3256.82 | 0.14894 |

Comment: I just added sample output used in rendering the graph and from what I can tell it is as expected based on the output from the original tutorial.